# Database migration service (DMS) memory consumption

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-dms

I'm trying to migrate a database from a server with MySQL to RDS Aurora MySQL using DMS. This database has thousands of schemas as we follow a "schema per customer" approach in our SaaS.

The migration task initially starts without any errors, but after some time, it fails due to excessive memory consumption.

> Last Error Replication task out of memory. Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL

I have checked the CloudWatch Metrics and noticed that the graph keeps increasing continuously. It appears that some data is being retained in memory, but I am not sure what and why.

[image: Cloudwatch memory usage]

I read some [articles](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/dms-memory-optimization)
on how to optimize memory consumption but I cannot find the right configuration to keep memory utilization under control.

Comment: Have you tried tuning [ChangeProcessingTuning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TaskSettings.ChangeProcessingTuning.html) for your DMS task? Please check the metrics of your replication instance when the task runs. If tuning DMS task settings does not work, you might want to check if your DMS replication instance type is the right one for your data migration.

Comment: I would also reach to AWS Support, as they might be able to get more details about memory being allocated for the task and how to optimize that